# Highcharts legend index showing -1 on legend click

Tags: javascript, debugging, indexing, highcharts

In this jsFiddle when all the series are de-selected except for series 1, it reads '-1'. Is this a bug in high charts or something I am doing wrong? I have tried a couple things, such as messing with the offset, showEmpty, nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/mhant47c/1/

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },

    yAxis: [{
      width: '33.33%',
      showLastLabel: false,
      id: 'yA0'
    }, {
      left: '33.33%',
      width: '33.33%',
      offset: 0,
      showLastLabel: false,
      id: 'yA1'
    }, {
      left: '66.66%',
      width: '33.33%',
      offset: 0,
      id: 'yA2'
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    xAxis:{
    showEmpty:false,
    categories:['a','b','c','d']
},
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }, {
      data: [3, 2, 1, 6]
    },
    {
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [23, 43, 56,23, 43, 56]
    },{
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [23, 43, 56,23, 43, 56]
    }, {
      yAxis: 2,
      data: [123, 413, 516,23, 43, 56]
    }]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart tries to center the columns which results in adding an additional category. To prevent this, use `min` option:

```
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        ...
    },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6p84vx53/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min